# ¿Como cambiar el servidor de LocalHost a 1**.**.2*.**:12**0 ? Node Js

Tags: nodejs

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy haciendo una aplicación que se tiene que conectar al servidor X en el puerto Y pero no sé como cambiar el servidor. Por defecto el node corre en mi LocalHost puerto 3000 y quiero cambiar esto para que corra en la ip X puerto Y que yo designe.

¿ Alguna idea de como hacer esto ? Googlie por todos lados pero no encuentro nada.

Muchas gracias a todos !

Comment: Ya probaste las respuestas que hay dentro de esta pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181253/changing-node-js-listening-port

Comment: No la había visto. Gracias che :)

Comment: Vale, si eso soluciona tu pregunta sería bueno que autorespondieras tu pregunta para las personas que lleguen aquí con el mismo problema